# Provision SQL Always On in Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

A bit brief about Always On SQL - One SQL Server VM acts as a primary Server and other SQL Server VM acts as a secondary Server. When primary isn't available, secondary acts as a primary and vice versa.

**Without Azure Resource Manager**
I had to provision the following :

1. Cloud service
2. Virtual Network
3. Storage Account
4. Virtual Machines for SQL server

**With Azure Resource Manager**
I had to provision the following :

1. Resource Group
2. Virtual Network
3. Storage Account
4. Virtual Machines for SQL Servers

Now when it comes to provision "without ARM", cloud service has a Public Virtual IP through which we can access the primary SQL Server if its up and running or else Secondary Server is shown up as Primary, ensuring no data loss (SQL Databases) or vice versa. This is done because we have a common VIP(Cloud service IP) to access.

But when it comes to provision "with ARM", there is no concept of cloud service, rather each and every Virtual Machine that is provisioned has Public IP addresses each.

So in that case how will i connect to the SQL machines as i need a common entry point to access the SQL Server

Comment: Generally, you would connect to these through an internal load-balancer in your virtual network.  For example, a web front end as part of the same virtual network would connect to SQL using the internal IP address of the LB in front of the servers.  Does that describe your situation or do you really want to expose the servers publicly?

Comment: @RickRainey In SQL Always On you have a Always On Listener. That Listener is assigned an IP same as that of the Cloud Service Public IP. (The IP for both is the same.) The Listener then redirects to the SQL Server VM whichever is active. This was possible without using ARM as their was a common IP (Cloud Service IP) unlike ARM.

Comment: The ARM way to do this would be to add a load balancer resource in front of your SQL cluster. Have you tried that?

Comment: Take a look at this example. Take a look at this example. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sql-server-2014-alwayson-existing-vnet-and-ad

Comment: Hey thanks @RickRainey i'll try it out and get back.

Comment: Hey @RickRainey could u give me some other way to contact you.

Comment: I tried using this example https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/sql-server-2014-alwayson-dsc/ and the provision was successful. Now how will i connect to the SQL Server Databases ??